# Using a KMeans to classify URLs: validate the number of cluster and visualise

Tags: k-means, plotting

I'm relatively new to the NLP and DataScience, so apologies for omission or things like this.

I've been trying to use the KMeans to classify a list of 1000 of unique URLs containing several keywords that span across the taxonomy of a site.
The intent is to understand how the algorithm would see these URLs fitting the best and - up to a degree - validate what the taxonomy exercise completed by the specialist.

The first step was to vectorise the URLs, obtaining an array of 1416 features.

I could run the KMeans without no problem, but here the first challenge: how can I verify the number of clusters. As far as I understand could be done with the Elbow algorithm, and the right number should be where the curve happens. 
In my case, it seems there is not a curve but a progressive degradation of the number of items falling in each group. See image for a range 1 to 40. If I have to see a curve, I'd say this is 17.

[image]

Assuming for a moment the number is correct, my next challenge is, how can I visualise the clusters and how can I understand about any outliers?

I thought that using a scatterPlot would have been a good idea, but with my data set this doesn't seem an option. I still have an array of 1464 feature each row vs the 2 data points needed.

Any idea on how I can proceed?

Comment: Did you find a way to cluster URLs? All the existing work seems to focus on domain based clustering. I want to cluster URLs based on pattern.

Comment: I've made progress since my original post. I was already on the right way, but my biggest learning is the approach is far to be perfect. Upon cleaning your data, and accepting the fact you might end up having unbalanced clusters, surely you can use this approach. All lies down to cleaning your data at first. The more the quality, the better the output. I would suggest also to look at this https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-text-plot-document-clustering-py

Comment: Did you use any vectorization technique to create the features or did you use a feature extraction step. For my issue I am struggling with vectorizing as just extracting the words from the URL removes the patter data

Comment: I used both, though a personalised feature extraction was more in line with my needs in the end. As much as I appreciate other people's work, there are nuances with some languages that are rarely covered in full. Totally agree we are talking about URLs, so removing stop-words and few other things are normally ok. But then there was some complexity due to the taxonomy that I had to factor in. FastText from Facebook was somehow of a help here, if this can help.